# Query will not print results vertically

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm attempting to run a query, it yields the correct data, but I don't want it to look like that.

```
    SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN TAX_TABLE.TAXVALUE = '0.06' THEN SALES_TABLE.TOTALSALE ELSE 0.0 END) AS 'TAX EXEMPT'
           SUM(CASE WHEN TAX_TABLE.TAXVALUE = '0.06' THEN SALES_TABLE.TOTALSALE ELSE 0.0 END) AS 'NOT EXEMPT'
           SUM(CASE WHEN TAX_TABLE.TAXVALUE = '0.065' THEN SALES_TABLE.TOTALSALE ELSE 0.0 END) AS 'TAX EXEMPT'
           SUM(CASE WHEN TAX_TABLE.TAXVALUE = '0.065' THEN SALES_TABLE.TOTALSALE ELSE 0.0 END) AS 'NOT EXEMPT'
           SUM(CASE WHEN TAX_TABLE.TAXVALUE = '0.07' THEN SALES_TABLE.TOTALSALE ELSE 0.0 END) AS 'TAX EXEMPT'
           SUM(CASE WHEN TAX_TABLE.TAXVALUE = '0.07' THEN SALES_TABLE.TOTALSALE ELSE 0.0 END) AS 'NOT EXEMPT'
           SUM(CASE WHEN TAX_TABLE.TAXVALUE = '0.075' THEN SALES_TABLE.TOTALSALE ELSE 0.0 END) AS 'TAX EXEMPT'
           SUM(CASE WHEN TAX_TABLE.TAXVALUE = '0.075' THEN SALES_TABLE.TOTALSALE ELSE 0.0 END) AS 'NOT EXEMPT'
    FROM ((ORDER_TB INNER JOIN SALES_TABLE ON ORDER_TB.RECID = SALES_TABLE.SALESID) 
           INNER JOIN TAX_TABLE ON ORDER_TB.SHIPZIPCODE = TAX_TABLE.ZCODE))
    WHERE(((ORDER_TB.STATENAME) = 'FL')
    AND ((ORDER_TB.SHIPDATE) BETWEEN 'MM/DD/YEAR' AND 'MM/DD/YEAR'))
```

If I run the query my results come out like this

```
    |TAX EXEMPT|NOT EXEMPT|TAX EXEMPT|NOT EXEMPT|TAX EXEMPT|NOT EXEMPT|TAX EXEMPT|NOT EXEMPT|
    |XXXXX.XX  |XXX.XX    |XXXXX.XX  |XXX.XX    |XXXXX.XX  |XXXX.XX   |XXX.XX    |XX.XX     |
```

I would like to show the results Like this

```
            |TAX EXEMPT|NOT EXEMPT|
            |XXXXX.XX  |XXX.XX    |
            |XXXXX.XX  |XXX.XX    |
            |XXXXX.XX  |XXXX.XX   |
            |XXX.XX    |XX.XX     |
```

I tried to do a group by and include TAX_TABLE.TAXVALUE in my SELECT

```
    GROUP BY TAX_TABLE.TAXVALUE
```

But when I do that It will just add 0.00 to the value corresponding to my CASE in my Query making the results much larger with unwanted Zeros. Is there somewhere in my CASES Which should be changed or would an UNPIVOT Be more Ideal?

Comment: If you only want 2 columns, you must only select two columns. There are a number of ways to do this (rework your cases into only 2 cases, properly means nesting them a lot; using UNION, using pivot etc); but it depends on where and how you'll use the data, because if it is *only* presentation, it should be handled in presentation and rarely the query.

Comment: How does your calculation logic differ for EXEMPT vs. NOT EXEMPT cases?

Comment: Are those case expressions real?

Comment: This is your real query or dummy strings for demonstration of the concept?

Comment: Oh, dummy of course.

Answer (score 0):

I Figured out how to do it thanks to @Allan. S Hansen. I'm new to this, I wasn't quite sure that you can add more than one WHEN to the CASE and was able to only yield two columns as wanted. Thanks for all your help.